# Check Date greater than 30 days from today's date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery datepicker and tried to find out difference between todays date and selected date , but getting issues... rather than issues... I was not able to find it perfectly...

I tried to do this on 'onSelect event of datepicker '

Question:
How to check whether selected Date using jQuery Datepicjer is greater than 30 days from todays date ?

Any help will be appreciated....!!
note: dont want to use any libraries, I need to solve this by using only jQuery.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Get the timestamp for 30 days from now:

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
//                                      day hour  min  sec  msec
```

Compare that timestamp with the timestamp for the selected date.

```
if (timestamp > selectedTimestamp) {
    // The selected time is less than 30 days from now
}
else if (timestamp < selectedTimestamp) {
    // The selected time is more than 30 days from now
}
else {
    // -Exact- same timestamps.
}
```

Comment: Solid code, but OP seems to be asking for 30 days in the future, not 30 days ago. Obvious to me its just a sign change, but might want to clarify for future stumblings.

Answer (score 5):

I have created one sample for you.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

Date: <input type="text" id="thedate"/>
<div id="checkDate">Check Date</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and Js

```
$('#thedate').datepicker();

$('#checkDate').bind('click', function() {
  var selectedDate = $('#thedate').datepicker('getDate');
  var today = new Date(); 
  var targetDate= new Date();
  targetDate.setDate(today.getDate()+ 30);
  targetDate.setHours(0);
  targetDate.setMinutes(0);
  targetDate.setSeconds(0);

  if (Date.parse(targetDate ) >Date.parse(selectedDate)) {
    alert('Within Date limits');
  } else {
    alert('not Within Date limits');
  }
});
```

You can check this code online [Here](http://jsbin.com/urutud/5/edit)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('input').datepicker({
    onSelect: function()
    {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var today = new Date();
        if((new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()+30))>date)
        {
             //Do somthing here..
        }

    },
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jeY7S/